# how to use hash sha256 password for pdo Login php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, hash, authentication

my register using hash 'sha256' password for database, i dont know the function that using for login with hash password.. i tried it but not fix or i need to use hash password for it ::

```
session_start();

try{
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=senio743_payless','senio743_peter', 'P@ssw0rd123');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
 die ('Error: '.$e->getMessage ()); 
}

$data = array ();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['con_id'])) {
    $conId= htmlspecialchars($_POST['con_id']);
  }

  if (isset($_POST['con_password'])) {
    $pass= htmlspecialchars($_POST['con_password']);
  }

  if ($conId==''||$pass=='') {
    $message="Fill in all the enteries";
    echo "<script>alert('".$message."');</script>";
    exit();
  }

  $query=  "SELECT * FROM `consumer` WHERE `con_id`='".$conId."' AND `con_password`= '".$pass."'";

  $prepare = $bdd->prepare($query);
  $exist = $prepare->execute();

  if ($exist) {
    if ($prepare->rowCount()>0) {
        $data[]=$prepare->fetch();
        foreach ($data as $datas) {
          $con_name=$datas['con_name'];
          $con_amount=$datas['con_amount'];
          //echo $mer_name;
        }
        $_SESSION['ID']= $conId;
        $_SESSION['name']= $con_name;
        $_SESSION['balance']= $con_amount;
       // $message="LOGIN Succesful";
        header("location:../consumer/summary.php");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['ID']= "";
        $_SESSION['name']= '';
        $_SESSION['balance']= 'Login Please';
        $message="Login not succesful";
        echo "<script>alert('".$message."');</script>";
        header("location:../login.php");
        exit();
    }
 }
```

please need help,
thank you..

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force with a popular password list.

Comment: PHP is suggesting that you do not use your own salt unless you really know what your doing.  Taken from the PHP site - "Warning The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use md5().

PHP has a password hashing function.

```
$options = [ 'cost' => 15 ];
$hashed_password = password_hash('password', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $hashed_password))
{
    // Password the same
}
else
{
    // Password failed
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

---

Using your script something along these lines may work as well

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 if ($conId==''||$pass=='') {
   $message="Fill in all the enteries";
    echo "<script>alert('".$message."');</script>";
    exit();
  }
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `consumer` WHERE `con_id`= :con_id";
  $prepare = $bdd->prepare($query);
  $prepare->bindParam(':con_id', $con_id);
  $prepare->execute();
  $exists = $prepare->fetch();

  $pass = hash('sha256', $_POST['pass']);
  if($pass == $exists['pass'])
  {
      // Passwords Match
  }
  else
  {
      // They Don't
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The hash function is just `hash('sha256', $pass);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Also, when logging someone in, I've always looked up the user my their username and then compared the passwords in PHP. It should be faster because the query doesn't have compare a 200 character string to thousands of other strings.

Comment: im sorry, im beginning php could you tell me how to use it on this code ?

Comment: When you create a user, you need to use the `hash` function above to turn the password into a hashed string. Then you store that string in your database. When someone attempts to log in, you select the user (at least the user ID and password) by the username the person entered. If the user is found, you then use the same hash function on the password the person entered on the login screen and compare (`===`) it to the hashed password from the data base. If they match, it was a valid login.